# Java 8 Lambda to create a Map where Value is a Wrapper Object of a list

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have this Address Class with me as a List and I wanted to create a Map with Street Name as the Key , and List of all Address Object as Values in which Street Name is part of it. Assume i get Address as a list , so i have with me a list of Address.

```
public class Address{
    private String streetName;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String zipCode;
    public String getStreetName() {
        return streetName;
    }
    public void setStreetName(String streetName) {
        this.streetName = streetName;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }
    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

}

I was able to do this using Lambda with the below Code

Map<String, List<Address>> resultMap =
addressList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(address-> address.getStreetName())); // This creates Map with street name as key and list of addresses as values
```

I have a need to create a Wrapper on Top of Address so that it looks like

```
public class AddressWrapper {
     private String streetName;
    private List<Address> addressWrapperList;
    public String getStreetName() {
        return streetName;
    }
    public void setStreetName(String streetName) {
        this.streetName = streetName;
    }
    public List<Address> getAddressWrapperList() {
        return addressWrapperList;
    }
    public void setAddressWrapperList(List<Address> addressWrapperList) {
        this.addressWrapperList= addressWrapperList;
    }
}
```

Now with the addressList i have, how can i create a Map so that 
instead of Street Name as Key and List of addresses belonging to that street name as value, i want to create a  Map with street name as Key but value as addressWrapperList ( which is a list of addresses )

Comment: `Map<String, AddressWrapper>`? But to be honest, why not use a `Map<String, List<Address>>`?

Comment: thats what i had originally but to  meet other functionalities i had to built such a map structure and so looking  for options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to go about it is to create a stream from the result of the `groupingBy` operation and collect to a `Map` specifying the value mapper function as an `AddressWrapper`.

```
Map<String, AddressWrapper> result = addressList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Address::getStreetName))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> {
                    AddressWrapper addressWrapper = new AddressWrapper();
                    addressWrapper.setStreetName(e.getKey());
                    addressWrapper.setAddressWrapperList(e.getValue());
                    return addressWrapper;
                }));
```

You can simplify the value mapper logic by creating a constructor with the signature  `public AddressWrapper(String streetName, List<Address> addressWrapperList) {...}`.

Then the code becomes:

```
Map<String, AddressWrapper> result = addressList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Address::getStreetName))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                              e -> new AddressWrapper(e.getKey(), e.getValue())));
```

Further, you can also achieve the same result with the `toMap` collector as follows:

```
Map<String, AddressWrapper> resultSet = addressList.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Address::getStreetName,
              e -> new AddressWrapper(e.getStreetName(),
                      new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(e))),
            (left, right) -> {
                left.getAddressWrapperList().addAll(right.getAddressWrapperList());
                return left;
            }));
```